# Is it possible to call Component using button (without using useState) in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I am using a button to display a modal for a particular profile (different buttons for different profiles). By using a hook, the modal just renders the last profile's info. (I am mapping the profile info list)

Is there a way I can call the modal component in the mapping itself without using Hook? Or any different approach to this problem?

(P.S the code is too long, hence not pasting it in the question description)

Comment: Please provide code snippet contaning relevant information, so we can take a look

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I found the solution.
Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I wired up parent and modal using another component in between, and it worked.
I created a component receiving props(containing profile info) from parent and passing it to the modal. And the modal is called from the parent via this new component.